# Check if telegram is getting data of link (user-agent is telegram)

Tags: php, user-agent

I have a website which user has to be logged in to his/her account to view pages ... but I want to set meta tags (description, image and title) for **only** when someone shares the link on telegram ...

how should I do it ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps an if statement?  Please post some code.

Comment: my friend which code ! :| I'm asking an obvious question

Comment: yeah just give those -1s :)
but it will help someone I'm certain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So. I'v found the answer by using server.com/test.php with contents:

```
file_put_contents("heh.txt", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Then I gave the link to telegram inside a chat.
the content of heh.txt was:

> TelegramBot (like TwitterBot)

so you should use:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === "TelegramBot (like TwitterBot)"){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same code with some checks. Code check if user agent present at the server environment and if usergent like telegram - do something

```
<?php
    $useragent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    if (stristr($useragent, 'TelegramBot'))
    {
  //do something
    }
?>
```